# IIS 8.5 re-installation gives 401 error to all the websites

Tags: asp.net, iis

After re-installing IIS 8.5, all the websites respond (**locally and externally**):

HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
Date: Tue, 29 Nov 2016 18:03:27 GMT
Content-Length: 0

Tried out granting access privilleges to the user, checking the Application Pool and etc.

What could be the fix?

Thanks and regards,
John

Comment: What is the authentication that is enabled on any of your site?

Comment: Thanks @RaviA. Anonymous and Forms Authentication

Comment: Can you check the IIS logs and see what is the sub status 401 1 or 401 2 or 401 3 . Also change the application pool identity to `Local System` and then test, if it works then definitely permission issue with folders.